# In OSGi, is passing a service reference a good practice or should bundles look it up on their own?

Tags: java, service, osgi, bundle, blueprint-osgi

I have these bundles:

- **Comm Service** provides a communication service.
- **Communication** is a communication bundle that uses the `Comm Service` to send/receive messages.
- **Poll** sends poll messages in multicast mode.

The `Communication` bundle is saturated and my approach is to implement other bundles for specific actions - the *Poll* bundle will be responsible for sending polls, the *Postcard* bundle for sending postcards, etc. (just some examples).

Is the approach to pass the `Comm Service` service as an input parameter for the `Poll` bundle when the `Communication` bundle needs to delegate its work of sending polls/postcards/message?

Is the snippet below correct?

*Communication bundle code*:

```
PollBundle p = new PollBundleImpl();
p.sendPoll(String pollQuestion, CommService cs);
```

Or is the better approach to let the `Poll`/`Postcard` bundles to retrieve the `Comm Service` service on their own?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **must not** pass the service object between bundles; if you do this then the OSGi Framework loses control over which bundles have visibility of the service and therefore it cannot inform the full set of bundles when that service needs to go away.

Therefore the Poll bundle must find the CommService for itself. There are a number of ways of doing this. I strongly recommend using **Declarative Services** from the OSGi Specification. Used in conjunction with [bnd annotations](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Components) you will be able to write the code of your Poll bundle as follows:

```
@Component
public class Polling {

    private CommService commService;

    @Reference
    public void setCommService(CommService cs) {
        this.commService = cs;
    }

    public void someMethodThatUsesCommService() {
         sendPoll(cs);
         // ...
    }
}
```

I recommend this approach over the Blueprint solution described by Jacek Laskowski in his answer because it does not require writing verbose and non-typesafe XML files, and it has better lifecycle characteristics that match the lifecycle of OSGi Services. However both the Declarative Services and Blueprint approaches are certainly safer than mucking about with the low-level OSGi APIs (e.g. `ServiceTracker`, `ServiceListener`).

Comment: Thanks Neil, I'm just a newbie with OSGi and I thought I could ask about this to start understanding bundles and their behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend to decouple the bundles leveraging [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) of the `OSGi Blueprint` (see **Blueprint Container Specification** in [OSGi Service Platform Enterprise Specification](http://www.osgi.org/Download/Release5), but mind it's for V5 release).

With the specification, you declare dependencies of a bundle using separate xml file(s) - `OSGI-INF/blueprint/*.xml` (the default, but can be changed with the `Bundle-Blueprint` header).

So, in your case you'll develop the `Comm Service` bundle whose service is a dependency of the `Communication` bundle. There are also the `Poll` and potentially the `Postcard` bundles of the same service interface that register the services so that they can become dependencies of the `Communication` bundle.

In such configuration, it's not the `Communication` bundle to pass the `Comm Service` bundle/service, but during initialization the `Poll` and `Postcard` bundles get their `Comm Service` service dependency.

Here's a hypothetical Blueprint configuration for the `Poll` bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
  <bean id="PollSenderBean" class="pl.japila.osgi.poll.PollSender">
    <argument ref="commService" />
  </bean>
  <service id="PollSenderBeanService" ref="PollSenderBean" 
           interface="pl.japila.osgi.Sender">
    <service-properties>
      <entry key="type" value="poll" />
    </service-properties>
  </service>
  <reference id="commService" interface="pl.japila.osgi.comm.CommService" />
</blueprint>
```

The `Postcard` bundle would be similar. Note the `entry` with the value of `poll` so you can get a specific service if there's a need for such queries.

A Blueprint configuration for the `Communication` bundle would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
  <reference-list activation="lazy" member-type="service-object"
                  id="Sender" interface="pl.japila.osgi.Sender" />
</blueprint>
```

Refer to the specification and perhaps [Apache Aries Blueprint module](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint.html) to study and learn the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some need of using a different `CommService` in different invocations of `p.sendPoll(String pollQuestion..)` I would say, let `PollBundle` find the `CommService` on its own.

Basically this reduces the coupling.  You only need to know about `PollBundle` to send a poll. This really depends on your architecture, but in general, the less objects you need to move around and the simpler your Interfaces, the better.